# Python: how to calculate data received and send between two ipaddresses and ports

Tags: python, sockets, network-traffic, traffic-measurement

I guess it's socket programming. But I have never done socket programming expect for running the tutorial examples while learning Python. I need some more ideas to implement this.

What I specifically need is to run a monitoring program of a server which will poll or listen to traffic being exchange from different IPs across different popular ports. For example, how do I get data received and sent through port 80 of 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.1 ( which is the gateway).

I checked out a number of ready made tools like MRTG, Bwmon, Ntop etc but since we are looking at doing some specific pattern studies, we need to do data capturing within the program.

Idea is to monitor some popular ports and do a study of network traffic across some periods and compare them with some other data.

We would like to figure a way to do all this with Python....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) for that. Just sniff all ethernet traffic on a particular interface, drop everything that is not TCP and doesn't match the port.

Not sure if scapy can already track TCP connections (stuff like recognizing duplicate sequence numbers, extracting just the payload stream) but I would guess it probably can, and if not it's not too hard to hack together a good-enough TCP connection tracker that works for 95% of the traffic.

Alternatives would be to use sockets directly (look for raw sockets) or libpcap, which can both be done from Python. You may also want to check out the filter experssion syntax of the 'tcpdump' commandline tool, maybe it can do what you want already.

I bet there are more specialized high-level tools for this, but I don't know them.

PS: if you don't know wireshark yet, go check it out and play around with it first. It can follow TCP streams and will teach you what TCP connection tracking means. Maybe its commandline binary, tshark, can be used to extract TCP streams for what you want.

Comment: I have been checking scapy tutorial and other stuff. No one seems to have indicated how to use scapy to find traffic between two IPs. Any ideas

Comment: It should be easy enough to extract this from the scapy docu (search for "sniff"). And you need some basic understanding of the TCP/IP protocol, if you are not sure why there are sequence numbers in TCP but not in IP, you better go to wikipedia first.

Answer (score 0):

IPTraf is an ncurses based IP LAN monitoring tool. Has a capability to generate network statistics including TCP,UDP,ICMP and some more.

Since you're thinking to execute it from python, you may consider to use screen (screen manager with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation) to overcome ncurses issues and you may want to pass logging and interval parameters to IPTraf which forces iptraf to log to a file in a given interval. Little bit tricky but eventually you can have what you are looking for by basically parsing the log file.